# Using a literal to display results from query

Tags: c#, sql, literals, sqldatareader

I'm trying to display multiple rows from a query into a literal in asp.net c#. Here is my code for doing so:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetUsersLeagues]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        SqlParameter userIDParam = new SqlParameter("@userId", userId);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(userIDParam);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (dReader.Read())
        {
            usersLeagues.Text = (dReader["LeagueName"].ToString());
        }
        dReader.Close();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

My issue is that the literal is only displaying one of the rows, i've tried this with a list box and all rows were displayed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try usersLeagues.Text += (dReader["LeagueName"].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the value of the `Text` property on each iteration:

```
while (dReader.Read())
{
    usersLeagues.Text = (dReader["LeagueName"].ToString());
}
```

Instead of that, you need to *concatenate* the values on each iteration:

```
while (dReader.Read())
{
   usersLeagues.Text += (dReader["LeagueName"].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

In the above example, using `+=` causes an append to the current value of `usersLeagues.Text`, instead of a replacement.

Comment: Excellent, thank you ! I get a } at the end of the results, any idea why this may be ?

Comment: @MattHill - Nothing jumps out from the code you posted. Could it be that you append the `}` later on? Or that this is in your database?

Comment: No I don't do either, it's strange. I can't see why either !

Comment: @MattHill - Debugging is your friend at such points. Debug through the loop looking at the value of `usersLeagues.Text`. See how it changes and when you get the `}`.